# Oracle variables bound (ORA-01008)

Tags: oracle, cakephp-2.0, oracle-call-interface

I'm very new to the Oracle variables bound Concept. whenever i request from client side the request is always running, it is not at all aborting. I was tried to find the current Query which is executing the Oracle DB. i got the following query. But if i run this query it is showing error. Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this. To select the records, I'm using cakePHP find with 'all''.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table table 
WHERE ((table.field1 LIKE :"SYS_B_0") OR (table.field2 LIKE :"SYS_B_1")) 
AND ((table.field3 = :"SYS_B_2") AND (table.field4 = :"SYS_B_3")
AND (table.field5 = :"SYS_B_4")) AND ((table.field6 IS NULL) 
OR (table.field7 != :"SYS_B_5")) AND table.field8 = table.field1;

outcome:
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You should  substitute all variables that begin with (:) (colon) (like :"SYS_B_0", :"SYS_B_1" etc.)  with actual values to run the query. When you send a request - those values are set - and then the query is executed.

Comment: This looks like an Oracle bug, most probably you do some very strange. Most probably you use Oracle `cursor_sharing` feature. So you sent an SQL without any bind variables into the database. Then Oracle's parser replaces all the literals with bind variable names. And something goes wrong here. Please provide the SQL query you sent into the database.

Comment: Here is the CakePHP find query : 

$this->Motors->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'fields' => $fieldsArray,
        'order' => $order,
        'group' => $group,
        'limit' => $limit
  )
    );

Comment: @Rocky - can you check what SQL is generated by CakePHP ?

Comment: In SQLDeveloper tool i'm using this query to know the current running query.

select sql_text from v$sqlarea where users_executing > 0;

This returned :
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table table 
WHERE ((table.field1 LIKE :"SYS_B_0") OR (table.field2 LIKE :"SYS_B_1")) 
AND ((table.field3 = :"SYS_B_2") AND (table.field4 = :"SYS_B_3")
AND (table.field5 = :"SYS_B_4")) AND ((table.field6 IS NULL) 
OR (table.field7 != :"SYS_B_5")) AND table.field8 = table.field1;

Answer (score 0):

Oracle saves all queries in a query cache (look at `select * fom v$sql`). As soon as a query is executed, Oracle checks the cache to see if that particular query is already there. If it is, it "knows" how to execute it, if it isn't, it has to make a query plan (which costs extra time) (this is called a "hard parse" in Oracle jargon).

If an application does not make use of bind variables, all literals (column values mostly) are stored in the cache. These queries:

```
select * from clients where name = 'Smith'
select * from clients where name = 'Jones'
```

are 2 different queries in the cache. Of course their plan would be the same (usually), but the database has no way of knowing that. This is inefficient use of Oracle's query cache (because it has 2 entries instead of 1) and database time (because it made 2 execution plans where 1 would be sufficient).

Therefore, a behaved application uses bind variables for all literals. The following query:

```
select * from clients where name = :bind_variable
```

always has the same execution plan. Before execution, the application can bind any literal value to the variable `:bind_variable`, e.g. 'Smith' or 'Jones' and the database will retrieve the correct record(s). It does not matter what value the application binds to the variable, for the database it will always be the same query and it will reuse the existing execution plan from the cache.

Now you can see what's wrong with your query: you didn't tell Oracle what values it needs to bind to the variables (or in plain English, what parameters to substitute).

Replace all ":bind_variable" occurrences with their respective values and the query should work.

Comment: Thanks Martin for replying. 

I'm using this query in request 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table WHERE table.field1 = 'honda' AND table.field2 = 'john';

Here 'honda' and 'john' values are coming from client side.
do we need to write any script to replace the literal values like (:SYS_B_0, :SYS_B_1) which are added to the actual SQL query.

If any script is needed to replace the Oracle system Literals(:SYS_B_0, :SYS_B_1).
Please suggest me the possible ways.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you just want to execute one specific query manually, then just replace the bind variables with literals and run it. You do not need a specific script.

Comment: Hello Martin.
Thanks for your time.
Finally i found the Solution. There is an issue with the existing SQL in the DATABASE.
Usually the Oracle query engine replaces the actual values with Oracle variables like "SYS_B_0", "SYS_B_1", And the original data will be stored in the system table .

Thanks.